# Can I move this code from erb to the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have 2 models `Auteur` and `Biblio` that both `have_and_belongs_to_many` of each other.

In the template displaying the Authors (auteur) and its books (biblio), I have this code :

```
<% @auteurs.each do |e|  %>
<p><%= e.nom_complet %>, <i> <%= e.biblios.map{|l| l.titre }.join(', ') %></i>, <%= e.biblios.map { |l| l.lieu }.join(', ') %>, <%= e.biblios.map { |l| l.annee }.join(', ') %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

As each biblio has 8 fields and can belong to different types according to its form of publication and type of content, this would lead to doing a lot of `map` and `if` statements in erb.

Although this works fine, there must be a better way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: you mean `has_and_belongs_to_many` right?

Comment: Instead of model you can move it to helper

Answer (score 1):

You can move this code as instance methods in `Author` model

```
def biblios_titre
  biblios.map(&:titre).join(', ')
end

def biblios_lieu
  biblios.map(&:lieu).join(', ')
end

def biblios_annee
  biblios.map(&:annee).join(', ')
end
```

And use it in views

```
<% @auteurs.each do |e|  %>
  <p><%= e.nom_complet %>, 
    <i><%= e.biblios_titre %></i>, 
    <%= e.biblios_lieu %>, 
    <%= e.biblios_annee %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If I do that, then title, year and place get mapped distinctly, leading to `titleonetitle, titletwotitle, titlethreetitle, Paris, New York, Moscow, 1965, 2014, 2012``

Comment: @thiebo, your comment changes a bit your question. Please, check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper method in the model.

```
def view_biblios
    self.nom_complet << "<i>" <<
           self.biblios.map(&:titre).join ", " <<
           "</i>, " << self.biblios.map(&:lieu).join ", " <<
           ", " << self.biblios.map(&:annee).join ", "
 end
```

And in the view

```
 <%= e.view_biblios.html_safe %>
```

**UPDATE**

Since you probably want to keep titles together, based on your comment, you may need this method instead

```
def view_biblios
    self.nom_complet << self.biblios.map{|b| 
         "<i>#{b.titre}</i>, #{b.lieu}, #{b.annee}"}.join ", "
 end
```

Comment: Great, thanks Ruby Racer ! This is pretty much what I did. (I have only 4 credits as I registered recently on SO, so I can't upvote you). If I can, I'll post below how I did this finally.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. In the end I did it this way. Using `each` was sufficient. The code below also has a bit of css, to titles appear indented below each author (in bold).

I'll do all the cleaning up of the code and moving pieces to helpers after I get my 8 models to communicate correctly :)

```
<% @auteurs.each do |e|  %>
<p><strong><%= e.nom_complet %></strong>

<% e.biblios.each do |l| %>
    <br><span id="indent"><i><%= l.titre %></i>, <%= l.lieu %>, <%= l.annee.to_s %></span>

    <% end %>
</p>
<% end %>
```